# Overloading method from generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I'm playing with the visitor pattern to traverse a heterogeneous object structure, and want to overload the `visit()` method in my generic interface to handle different subtypes differently.  Why doesn't `visit(Bar)` get called in the code below, and is there anything I can do to fix it? Thanks in advance for your help!

Steve

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OverloadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a visitable collection
        FooCollection c = new FooCollection();

        // Add some members
        c.add(new Foo());
        c.add(new Bar());

        // Visit
        c.accept(new IVisitor<Foo>() {

            public void visit(Foo foo) {
                System.out.println("Foo");
            }

            public void visit(Bar bar) {
                System.out.println("Bar");
            }
        });
    }

    public static class Foo {
    }

    public static class Bar extends Foo {
    }

    public static interface IVisitor<T> {

        public void visit(T object);
    }

    public static class FooCollection {

        private final ArrayList<Foo> m_list = new ArrayList<>();

        public void accept(IVisitor<Foo> visitor) {
            for (Foo foo : m_list) {
                visitor.visit(foo);
            }
        }

        public void add(Foo foo) {
            m_list.add(foo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @ernest_k, I could not get that code to format correctly!

Comment: It calls with `Foo` because the type of the parameter is `Foo`. Try casting it to `Bar`

Comment: @ayrton, cast it where?

Comment: My guess is you're unable to override a superclass method twice

Comment: When methods are overloaded, the **static** types of the parameters determine which method is called. This is related to [Double Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)

Comment: @Turing85 So I would have to have Foo and Bar implement an accept() method of their own, and call it from FooCollection.accept() to get it to dispatch using the dynamic type?

Comment: This smells awfully like an [XY-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is your actual use case? Why do you need to distinguish between `Foo` and `Bar`?

Comment: @Turing85 It's a game inventory that can contain both unique non-duplicable items (e.g. "rusty knife") as well as stackable typed items ("5 candles"). The view needs to pull the quantity from the stacked items and display it, and use it determine whether to use the singular or plural noun. I really don't want that code in the domain objects.

Comment: This should not be a concern of the View, but of some controller- or presenter-layer. Every `Item` should have some corresponding `Presenter` that pulls the necessary information from a specific `Item`. You can choose the correct `Presenter` through, e.g., a [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Your visitor in `public void accept(IVisitor<Foo> visitor)` implements `IVisitor<Foo>` so, the only visible method is `public void visit(Foo foo)`.
One option to fix this is to leave IVisitor generic (removing the `<Foo>` from interface declaration). The method on it become:

```java
public void visit(Object object);
```

Another option is change the method accept to:

```java
public void accept(IVisitor<Object> visitor) {
...
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, the default implementation visit(Object) gets called instead of the overloads.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I modify IVisitor to include a method for each desired type:

```
public static interface IFooVisitor {
    public void visit(Foo foo);
    public void visit(Bar bar);
}
```

and implement an accept() method for each:

```
public static class Foo {       
    public void accept(IFooVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}

public static class Bar extends Foo {
    public void accept(IFooVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

I lose some flexibility and couple Foo and Bar to the visitor pattern, but it works.